# Insert into a nested array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have cars described in a file in this form:

```
CAR
Audi
1x1
XXX
XXXXX
_X
_X
```

I want to insert the cars from this file into a  10 x 10 nested array.
The second line are coordinates (R x C) from the left top point for the start of the car. Third to fifth lines show the shape of the car.

```
OUTPUT= [["O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O"],
    ["O","X","X","X","O","O","O","O","O","O"],
    ["O","X","X","X","X","X","O","O","O","O"],
    ["O","O","X","O","O","O","O","O","O","O"],
    ["O","O","X","O","O","O","O","O","O","O"]
    ["O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O"]
    ["O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O"]
    ["O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O"]
    ["O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O"]
    ["O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O","O"]

INPUT arr =[]
```

[image: Grid with first car]

Comment: Is this the content of one fole or two files?

Comment: it's only one csv file

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. If it's a csv where are commas? What's the expected output? Something like `[["Audi", 2, 2], [BMW, 5,1]]`? I can not understand the Xs, for Audi it's 4 lines, for BMW are 3 lines. Can edit the post with more details?

Comment: Sorry its TXT I mistaken it with another assignment. I have modified the description and add img.

Comment: `Third to fifth line shows the of the car.` you're missing a word here. It's really hard to answer this without more info, such as the desired output format

Comment: Output format is just 2D Array with the cars based on coordinates, like in the picture.

Comment: Can you give input *and* output in Ruby form?

Comment: What have you tried? What issues are you having? Where are you stuck? Have you made any progress that you can show us on your own to attempt to solve the assignment?

Comment: Your `output` is not valid.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work, pretty tricky. Sure there is a better way.

**First map the file into a hash.**

```
car_array = []
File.open('car_array.txt').each_with_index do |line, idx|
    car_array << line.chomp
end
p car_array
# => ["CAR", "Audi", "1x1", "XXX", "XXXXX", "_X", "_X", "CAR", "BMW", "5x1", "__X", "XXX", "X", "XX"]

car_hash = {}
key = nil
car_array.each_with_index do |e, index|
  key = car_array[index-1].downcase.to_sym if car_array[index-2] == "CAR"
  car_hash[key] = [e] if car_array[index-2] == "CAR"
  car_hash[key] << e if car_hash[key] unless (car_array[index-2] == "CAR" || car_array[index-1] == "CAR" || car_array[index] == "CAR")
end

p car_hash
# => {:audi=>["1x1", "XXX", "XXXXX", "_X", "_X"], :bmw=>["5x1", "__X", "XXX", "X", "XX"]}

car_hash.transform_values do |array|
  h = {start: [], points: []}
  h[:start] = array[0].split('x').map(&:to_i).map!{ |e| e}
  (array.size - 1).times do |n|
    h[:points] << array[n+1]
  end
  array[0] = h
  (array.size - 1).times do |n|
    array.pop
  end
end

car_hash.transform_values! {|v| v[0]}

p car_hash
# => {:audi=>{:start=>[1, 1], :points=>["XXX", "XXXXX", "_X", "_X"]}, :bmw=>{:start=>[5, 1], :points=>["__X", "XXX", "X", "XX"]}}

car_hash.each_value do |car|
  car[:points].map! do |point|
    point.scan(/./)
  end
  row = car[:start][0] - 1
  col = car[:start][1] - 1
  car[:points].map! do |points|
  delta_col = 0
  row += 1
    points.map! do |point|
      delta_col +=1
      point == 'X' ? [row, col + delta_col] : nil
    end
    points.compact
  end
  car[:points] = car[:points].flatten(1)
end


p car_hash
# => {:audi=>{:start=>[1, 1], :points=>[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 2], [4, 2]]}, :bmw=>{:start=>[5, 1], :points=>[[5, 3], [6, 1], [6, 2], [6, 3], [7, 1], [8, 1], [8, 2]]}}
```

**Then us the hash to build the table.**

```
table_model = Array.new(10) {Array.new(10,'O')}

def print_table (table)
  table.each {|row| p row}
end

audi_table = table_model.dup

car_hash[:audi][:points].each { |point| audi_table[point[0]][point[1]] = 'x' }

print_table audi_table

# => ["O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
# => ["O", "x", "x", "x", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
# => ["O", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
# => ["O", "O", "x", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
# => ["O", "O", "x", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
# => ["O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
# => ["O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
# => ["O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
# => ["O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
# => ["O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]
```